# Git Hook `post-receive` with `git pull` runs well via command line but returns empty string on automatic hook

Tags: git, githooks

Just like many, I am trying to create a `post-receive` hook on a server-side remote git. The following is my code:

`cd [LIVE SITE DIR] && git pull origin master | wall`

I have added the `wall` so that it can be broadcasted and I can receive the notice. One thing that I noticed is when I run `./post-receive`, it all works fine.

```
Broadcast message from root (Tue Oct  8 14:58:13 2013):

Updating 7ebd925..1a25791
Fast-forward
 html/header.php | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

But, when I tried to do a `git push` , `./post-receive` seems to be called but I received the following empty broadcast:

```
Broadcast message from root (Tue Oct  8 14:53:32 2013):
```

I have tried to include `pwd`, `ls` command into the `post-receive` and everything works fine for both situations. Except for the `git pull` that it seems to return an empty output.

Have gone through all the suggestions provided in SO but to no avail :(. Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems because one of the files in `.git` which is `HEAD` has `root` as the file owner. The above shell script was executed using another user.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure your `post-receive` hook unset `GIT_DIR`, or it will still refer to the git repo of the hook, instead of the git repo of the live site you just `cd` in.

```
cd [LIVE SITE DIR]
unset GIT_DIR
git pull
```

Or:

```
cd [LIVE SITE DIR]
env -i origin master
```

Or:

```
cd [LIVE SITE DIR]
git --git-dir=[LIVE SITE DIR]/.git pull
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempts. Tried all of the above but everything returns  empty string on automatic invoking.

Comment: @HeruS Ok. Independently of the broadcast issue, I would still recommend unsetting `GIT_DIR`. Now, is wall the right tool? See http://serverfault.com/a/390417/783. Is `rwall` a better choice?

Comment: independent from `wall` or `rwall` somehow the git pull is still not executed. :(